# "x is not a function" in js when using class

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, function, class

I am new to JS and especially class in JS.
I don't fully understand how classes work. Please help me in the following question.
This is a simple page with a button. I want it to run a function (doThis()) after clicking the button. But it gives an error saying the function is not defined.

```js
class Test {
    constructor() {
        this.button = document.getElementById("but1");
        this.button.addEventListener("click", this.butClick);
    }
    butClick() {
        console.log("clicked");
        this.doThis();
    }
    doThis(){
        console.log("Inside doThis")
    }
}
t1 = new Test();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="but1">Click me</button>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Inside of a clicked event listener, this refers to the button, not your class. I can't tell you why its that way, but that should hopefully help you fix the problem.

Comment: You could bind the function, but an easier option is to just use an arrow function -> ` this.button.addEventListener("click", () => this.butClick());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.button.addEventListener("click", this.butClick);` should be `this.button.addEventListener("click", this.butClick.bind(this));`.

Without `bind(this)`, the `this` inside `butClick` is just the `button` element, not the `class Test`.

Answer (score -1):

```js
class Test {
constructor() {
}
butClick() {
    console.log("clicked");
    this.doThis();
}
doThis(){
    console.log("Inside doThis")
  }
}

t1 = new Test();

const button = document.getElementById("but1")
button.addEventListener('click', event => {
event.preventDefault()
// Call doThis method on t1, the instance...
t1.doThis()
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="but1">Click me</button>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have done some short and helpful article on using classes in JS, should help, go to the article [here](https://maye.pwafire.org/articles/javascript-classes).

Comment: That's not a good choice, especially if you have multiple instances.  And with it been a class that is often likely.